# SQL query to return ids of duplicate rows by value

Tags: mysql, sql

Given

```
CREATE TABLE `region` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_region_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL
```

And records like:

```
1|300|new york|
2|300|new york|
3|500|seattle|
4|800|los angeles|
5|999|los angeles|
6|600|huston|
7|600|huston|
```

How do I run an SQL query that will return all duplicates by 'name' with equal parent_region_id. For example, given data above, I should get two results:

```
1,2 
6,7
```

but not

```
4,5
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a self-join on the table

```
select t1.id,
t2.id
from region t1 
inner join region t2
on t1.name = t2.name
and t1.parent_region_id = t2.parent_region_id
and t1.id <> t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) c 
FROM region 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING c > 1
```

Comment: Missing records ids in the result as in my example above.